# Returning multiple values in python, from csv

Tags: python, regex, csv, return

I'm working with a CSV-file, from which I might get multiple values. For example, a file with books, which might have multiple writers, for example `{Ben Norrington|Chad Andersson}`. They have together written a book.

In my code, I'm using regular expressions to split by the `|` and take remove the `{` and the `}`. It works fine.

The problem comes when I want to return the names of the writers. I only get the first name, not the second. How do I get both?

This is my code that takes a column from the CSV-file. The code is written in `python 2.7`

```
def ifseveral(x):
        if "{" not in x and "(" not in x and x != "NULL":
                return x
        elif "{" in x:
                splits =""
                splits = x.split("|")
                for i in splits:
                        string = i
                        string = re.sub('[{}]', '', string)
                        if "(" in string:
                                splitpar = ""
                                splited = string.split("(")
                                splitpar += splited[0][0:]
                                return splitpar
                        else:
                                **return string** #here is the problem

        else:
                return "No information available"
```

Comment: You could simplify `splitpar = ""; splited = string.split("("); splitpar += splited[0][0:]` to just `splitpar = string.split("(")[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Return breaks the loop, therefore only the first split will be returned. You have to adjust your logic so that you add your splits to a datatstructure (or even a simple string) and return the entire structure after the for loop.
This could do the job though it's untested.

```
def ifseveral(x):
        if "{" not in x and "(" not in x and x != "NULL":
                return x
        elif "{" in x:
                splits =""
                splits = x.split("|")
                return_value = ""
                for i in splits:
                        string = i
                        string = re.sub('[{}]', '', string)
                        if "(" in string:
                                splitpar = ""
                                splited = string.split("(")
                                splitpar += splited[0][0:]
                                return splitpar
                        else:
                                return_value += string+" "
                return return_value

        else:
                return "No information available
```

Answer (score 1):

A function can return only a single object. That object can be a simple object such as an integer, or a string, or it can be a more complex object such as a list of objects or it can be a generator.

The `return` statement returns from the function.  The function does not (can not) continue executing.

Since you put a `return` statement in a `for` loop, when the return is reached the loop no longer continues to process additional data.

One solution: build a list and return it

```
def ifseveral(x):
    # ...
    result = []
    for string in splits:
        # ...
        if "(" in string:
            splitpar = ""
            splited = string.split("(")
            splitpar += splited[0][0:]
            result.append(splitpar)
        else:
            result.append(string)

    return result

foo = ifseveral("something")
print(foo)
print(len(foo))
for name in foo:
    print("One of the names is", name)
```

Another solution is for your function to be a generator:

```
def ifseveral(x):
    # ...
    for string in splits:
        # ...
        if "(" in string:
            splitpar = ""
            splited = string.split("(")
            splitpar += splited[0][0:]
            yield splitpar
        else:
            yield string

    return result

foo = ifseveral("something")
print(foo)
for name in foo:
    print("One of the names is", name)
```